# python method argument recognize comma (not passing argument)

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

here's method

```
def method(table_name, find_value=None, skip=None)


mothod('table_name',find_value={'milestones.title': {'$regex': 'September'}},{'milestones'}
```

there is comma in find_value

Is there a way to prevent a comma in an argument from being passed to the next parameter?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a `tuple` as an argument then you must include parentheses round the tuple. Normally when you have a tuple in Python the parentheses are optional, but sometimes (as here) they are needed to avoid the comma being interpreted as something other than separating the tuple elements.

This passes 2 arguments to `method`:

```
def method(table_name, find_value=None, skip=None)

method(
   'table_name',
   find_value=({'milestones.title': {'$regex': 'September'}},{'milestones'}))
```

Comment: Thank you!! 
print(find_value)  >>>>
({'milestones.title': {'$regex': 'September'}}, {'milestones'})
//// want_value >>> {'milestones.title': {'$regex': 'September'}}, {'milestones'}

Comment: Those are the same value, the printed form of the `tuple` includes the parentheses.

Comment: Is that so? But it doesn't work. in find method >>>>
db_path[table_name].find(find_value)

Comment: is ok >>>  db_path[table_name].find({'milestones.title': {'$regex': 'September'}},{'milestones'})